# Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT (E_FAIL))

Tags: .net, silverlight, pivotviewer

I'm receiving this error when I attempt to drag a PivotViewer control onto MainPage.xaml.

[image]

The steps that led me to this point are the following...

1. Installed PivotViewer SDK
2. Created a new Silverlight Business Application
3. Added a reference to System.Windows.Pivot
4. Added this to my UserControl tag in the XAML:

   xmlns:pivot="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Pivot;assembly=System.Windows.Pivot"
5. Dragged PivotViewer control onto MainPage.xaml

Any solutions?

**EDIT**  Here's more info on the error message

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_Add[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, Object value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.AddImpl(Object value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateChildren(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, DocumentCompositeNode compositeNode, Boolean isNewInstance)
```

Answer (score 1):

The PivotViewer requires the Silverlight toolkit.  Do you have the toolkit referenced in your project?  It might be bombing because of that.